# How to check if more than one character is uppercase in a string in Java

Tags: java

How to check if one string has more than one uppercase character (two or more next to each other)  in Java?
I've tried:

```
String word = scanner.nextLine();
for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++) {
char value = word.charAt(i);
if(Character.isUpperCase(value) && Character.isUpperCase(value+1) {
     System.Out.Print("There is more than one character uppercase");
   }
}
```

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thanks! But that way it will count if there are others uppercase letters too. I want to check if there are 2 or more uppercase letters in a row.

Comment: @TannerDolby It would be easier to just save the last isUpperCase check while iterating. Any approach to this solution will be linear, because this is a linear problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Character.isUpperCase(value+1)` does not have the desired outcome in your case, it will simply add `1` to your character value, it will not get the next character in your `word` `String`. To get the next character try to use `Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(i+1))`.

Doing this, you should also be wary of `StringIndexOutOfBounds` exception, that's why
`word.length() > i+1` is being used:

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 String word = scanner.nextLine();
 for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++) {
      if(Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(i))) {
           if( word.length() > i+1 && Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(i+1)) ){
               System.out.println("There is more than one character uppercase");
           }
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are adding `1` to `value`, but `value` is a `char`.

I corrected this mistake, it should work now:

```
public boolean duplicateUpperCase(String word) {
    boolean lastUpperCase;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        boolean upperCase = Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(i));
        if (lastUpperCase && upperCase) return true;
        lastUpperCase = upperCase;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now to check:

```
String word = scanner.nextLine();
if (duplicateUpperCase(word)) System.out.println("There is more than one character uppercase");
```